# Phonegap Plugin to Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to add facebook login plugin in my Phonegap project, but it's returning `404` error

```
cordova plugins add com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect --variable APP_ID="123456" --variable APP_NAME="MYAPP"

Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect
```

I also tried [Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), but it's also returning error to me:

[image: Phonegap plugin add error]

What Phonegap plugin can I use to login with Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

At the starting i get the error message.Then i changed the plugin into 
" **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"** "

This work fine for me

Comment: Thanks for your (probably useful) answer. However, it starts off seeming like a question. Would you like to rephrase it a little? At the risk of seeming pedantic, I recommend to change from "i get" to "I also got the same"; which might change the whole impression.